References for delayed differential equations
I would like to read some good introduction to the study of "delayed differential equations". I am not sure for the terminology ... but I am talking about equations of the form : $y'(x) = f(y(x - a))$ where $a$ is a given real number. Any hint would be appreciated.
I was led to this question after trying to solve : $f(x) = x\,f'\left(\frac x2\right)$, which after a change of variable is transformed into $g'(x)=\frac12\,g\left(x+\ln(2)\right)$. I have my own solution for this latter problem, but I am interested in reading someone else's solution too.

Introduction to Time-Delay Systems by Emilia Firdman is a good book to get a bright overview about the topic!

@zinsinho Thank you ! I will try to find it.
